# The probability of every passenger getting a seat.

Tags: probability, contest-math

> There are $9$ seats for passengers in a bus. Probability of ticket buyer of the bus remains absent of the day of the journey is $50\%$. If the owner of the bus sell $11$ tickets then find the probability of every passenger getting a seat.

I am really newbie in probability. So can't find way to start.
**Source**: BdMO 2015 Cox Bazar Regional Higher Secondary question no. 6.

Comment: Find the probability that 10 or 11 people show up. Can you calculate that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order for every (present) passenger to get a seat, there must at least $2$ absentees.  We can determine this directly, but it's easier to get the complement: in order for a passenger to *not* get a seat, there must be $0$ or $1$ absentees.

Individual attendence is composed of independent bernoulli trials of equal probability, so we can use the [Binomial Distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution).

What is the probability that there are $0$ absentees?  What is the probability that there is $1$ absentee?  Add these together, and subtract from $1$, to get the final probability.

Answer (score 1):

The only ways that somebody would be left without a seat would be if either 10 or 11 people showed up.
you should use the binomial distribution with $p=q=\frac 12$ 
$$ P = 1 - \binom {11 }{10} \left(\frac12 \right)^{10}  \left(\frac12 \right)^{1}  - \binom {11 }{11} \left(\frac12 \right)^{11} \left(\frac12 \right)^{0}$$

$$ = 1 - 12 \left(\frac12 \right)^{11} $$